# How to set one test case for two different browsers in Protractor JS?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I want to run same test case on two different browser but it should output another result for each other.

For example, check out the test case below, one test step is capturing screenshot 
only for Chrome and the other one should capturing the screenshot only for FireFox.

Note the comments inside the test case, I've duplicated the code block that I wanna run for a different browser.

Please your help.

Thanks.

**Test case**

```
describe ('Login', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
     });

    it ('Enter to the home page', function() {
        browser.driver.get('https://user:pass@www.website.com/');
        browser.driver.sleep(1000);
            expect (browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('meet2know.com');
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        //--- Capture Screenshoot for FF---
        browser.driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data){
            var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
            var fs = require("fs");
                fs.writeFile("homePage.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                });
        });
        //--- Capture Screenshoot for Chrome only ---
        browser.driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data){
            var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
            var fs = require("fs");
                fs.writeFile("homePage-chrome.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

**Protractor Conf**

```
//var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require("fs");
exports.config = {
  chromeDriver: 'npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
  chromeOnly: false,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['login.js'],
  // specs: ['login.js', 'onboarding.js'],

  //specs: ['./Scripts/*.js'],

  multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'firefox',
      'cli': {
      'args': ['webdriver.firefox.useExisting=default']
      // 'args': ['webdriver.firefox.useExisting=default', '-jsconsole', '-jsdebugger']
}}, {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    args: ['--test-type','--memory-metrics','--console','--crash-on-failure','--load-extension=' + 'C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj\\1.2.4_0'] 
    } 
}],

  // rootElement: '.main',
  framework: "jasmine",
  allScriptsTimeout: 10000,
  getPageTimeout: 10000,
  onPrepare: function() {
    require('C:\\automation\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
    );
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return browser.driver.get('http://user:pass@www.website.com');
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      onComplete: null,
      // If true, display spec names.
      isVerbose: true,
      // If true, print colors to the terminal.
      showColors: true,
      // If true, include stack traces in failures.
      includeStackTrace: true,
      // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 660000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want a single function to run after `takeScreenshot()` that will save the screenshot to a different file depending on which browser is running.  Is that right?

If so, you can query Protractor for the browser name (see [Get the current browser name in Protractor test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872955/get-the-current-browser-name-in-protractor-test)).  You can follow the instructions to patch "browser" with the name (making it a bit more accessible), or fetch the name on demand.  Using that to name your file would look something like this:

```
browser.driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data){
    var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
    var fs = require("fs");
    return browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
        var browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
        var fname = "homePage-" + browserName + ".png";
        fs.writeFile(fname, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, you probably want to use `writeFileSync` or make sure you use a promise to tell Protractor to wait until your screenshot is written.  (Resolve the promise in the completion handler.)

Comment: Is there way to call this code part instead to write it every test case? Something like 'captureScreen("onboarding-screen1-heb-" + browserName + ".png")' ? @P.T.

Comment: @IdanE Just put the whole thing in a function, and it should work fine.