# How we can pass the browser name through command prompt in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber frame work with protractor 5.2.2. and cucumber 3.2.1. i have to pass browser name through command prompt instead of hard coding in config file.

Comment: You can use `browser.browserName` to get the name.

Comment: I am able pass to pass browser name through command prompt and run in chrome and Firefox but not in internet explorer.I have used the command "protractor cucumber.conf.js --capabilities.browserName=internetexplorer" and the error is "SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@5ca001a9"
In my config file ,i have given 
capabilities: { 'browserName' : " '' }

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872955/get-the-current-browser-name-in-protractor-test) a solution to your problem? Why do you have to pass it via command line instead of taking it from config

Comment: Actually my requirement is user should be able to run  the script in a single browser or in multiple browsers  without hard coding the browser name in the config file .

Comment: It is not hardcoded. It is automatically discovered by the framework. You just read the value. If you run it in chrome it returns chrome if you run it in ie it returns ie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:** Specify the browser name in cmd line only to make script run on that browser.

```
 // conf.js
 capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
 }
```

`protractor conf.js --browser=firefox` // will run on firefox 
`protractor conf.js` // with run on chrome

**Case 2:** Want to use the browser name for some code logic before protractor runner launched

You can use `process.argv` to get all stuff in command and extract the browser name you passed-in.

```
// cmd.params.js 
// parse cmd parameters

var params = {};
process.argv.slice(3).forEach(function (arg) {
    let flag = arg.split('=')[0];
    let value = arg.split('=')[1];
    let name = flag.replace('--', '');

    params[name] = value;
});

module.exports = params;
```

```
// conf.js
var params = require('./cmd.params.js');

var browser = params.browser;
// now you can use the variable: browser anywhere in conf.js    

var multiCapabilities = browser.split(',').map(function(browserName){
    return {
        browserName: browserName.trim()
    };
})

exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities: multiCapabilities
    ....
};
```

`protractor conf.js --browser=firefox` // will run only on firefox

`protractor conf.js --browser="firefox, chrome"` // will run on firefox and chrome

Comment: Its useful. when i have used protractor conf.js --browser=firefox,  protractor conf.js --browser="internet explorer", i am able to run in single browser.Can we run the script in 2 or 3 browsers at a time by specifying the browser names in cmd line?I have used " protractor conf.js --browser=firefox,chrome " .but its not working

Comment: I have created the file cmd.params.js in my project folder and made changes in config file but when i have run the script, i got an error "Error message: failed loading configuration file cucumber.conf.js" , "ReferenceError: moduel is not defined"

Comment: A type error in cmd.params.js, should be `module.exports`

Comment: I have tried but the error is still existing.How can we solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is possible to upload your cucumber.conf.js and cmd.params.js to your github account, I will look into and modify it and commit back.